# can i check if an element is available before I use XSP.partialRefreshGet to update it?

Tags: xpages

since the ID of a control in xpages is dynamic I cannot a normal selector to check if the element exists on the xpage e.g.

```
if (document.getElementById("myElementId")) {
   XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:myElementId}", {});
}
```

what alternative do I have? a "partial" ID selector?

Comment: if (document.getElementById("#{id:pnlHistoryContainer}")){   
   XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:pnlHistoryContainer}");
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried:

```
if (document.getElementById("#{id:myElementId}")) {
   XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:myElementId}", {});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of approaches you can take. The most direct is the one Michael pointed out in his answer.

Another efficient one is [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). Is is more flexible since you can lookup using classes or element types or any combination of it. It’s the same selectors you use in CSS.

This is handy in case the element is client created. There is als [quertySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) that allows to get more elements. A use case: make sure exactly 3 items are selected (user comfort, not integrity).